# Is there a word or phrase used to describe romantic partners of a family both married and unmarried?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In a family with multiple married adult children, the non-blood spouses could be referred to, as a group, as the in-laws of the family.

If I also wanted to include unmarried partners (boyfriends/girlfriends), is there some word or phrase I could use?

I've searched on here and Google and get results relating to common law marriages which is definitely not what I'm looking for.

Who did you invite to the activity while the family is taking care of personal family stuff on our group vacation?
All <in-laws, boyfriends, and girlfriends> were, even the new ones.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Adding example sentences -

My father-in-law is throwing a birthday party. All <word/phrase for the family's in-laws and unmarried partners of the family> are invited.

I am putting together a document to share with <word/phrase> to help them when talking with my mom-in-law so they don't bring up topics that might offend her.

Who did you invite to the activity while the immediate family took care of personal family matters on our group vacation?
I invited all of the <word/phrase>, even the new ones.

Comment: They could just be called "partners" depending on context. There's the general "wives and girlfriends" abbreviated to WAGs but it's not quite a match. Can you give an example sentence or context, eg legal, wedding planning, genealogy, formal, affectionate?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, [family name], in-laws, and plus-ones.

[M-W plus-ones](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plus-one)
a person who accompanies an invited guest to an event or gathering at which guests are allowed to bring a companion or partner